# React Native - Unable to Upload Image Via Axios Post (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, axios

I'm unable to upload an image from my React Native application in Android (iOS works fine). On attempting to upload, I'm receiving the following error:

> Error: Network Error
>       at createError (buildURL.js:33)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:144)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:576)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:392)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.js:505
>       at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:190)
>       at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:344)
>       at MessageQueue.js:107
>       at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:291)

All other requests work, connection is configured to my local static IP address, as I'm testing on a physical device, rather than in a simulator.

I've looked at a number of solutions already:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9506

  - Suggests to add a `type` filed to `data`, which I had already (detailed below)
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404

  - Suggests to use IP instead of `localhost`, which I have been doing since the start

Here is the code that handles this:

`ProfileImage.js` (wrapper for `react-native-image-picker`):

```
async onHandleResizedImageUri(image) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("profile_image", {
    uri: image.path,
    name: image.name,
    type: "image/jpeg"
  });

let imageUploadSuccess = await global.api.callPostImage("/api/profile-image", data);
```

`Api.js`

```
async callPostImage(url, data) {
  try {
    const settings = {
      baseURL: config.api_host,
      timeout: 1000,
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };

    const response = await this.axios.post(url, data, settings);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Also, this issue is happening in both `debug` and `release` mode, and for multiple servers (local, staging and production). All other network requests work fine, but this one will not complete. Anyone have any suggestions?

Device information:

- Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017)
- Model SMA520W
- Version 8.0.0

Comment: Hi, Did you solve it? Having same issue.

Comment: I personally didn't, but looking at the code that's in production, this is the only apparent change: `uri: (Platform.OS==='android' ? 'file://' : '') + image.path,` (as long as `import { Platform } from 'react-native';` is included too)

Comment: I have already tried the above suggestion but thank you for quick the reply

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the same problem. I'm using react-native-image-picker to get the path of the image, I wonder if it might be some issue with the path

Comment: @DanielTovesson I'm afraid not, and unfortunately I no longer have access to this code.

Comment: I solved it after a couple of hours, it was axios failing because I did not set Content-Type multipart/form-data